# How to use Node.js+Socket.io+Redis for online user list, real time/persisted message?

Tags: node.js, redis, socket.io

I am working on an application which has a chat feature using some third party tool(Moxtra), 
but it gives the ability to chat with other user using api apart from this i want several other features as following..

1. Show list of online user.
2. User can send real time notification(not chat) to other online user.
3. User can send messages which can be real time or if user is unavailable it would be persisted somewhere, 
   and when he comes back msg should be available to him.

Previously i have used ActiveMQ for notification and message but it seems its not that thing which i needs.

Now I have started work on above things using node.js, socket.io and redis.
I came around the solution to show online user using below code

server.js

```
var users = [];
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);

http.listen(3000, function(){
  console.log('listening on *:3000');
});

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.sendfile(__dirname + '/');
});

io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {

    socket.on('adduser', function (user) {
        console.log("adding user : " + user.id);
        socket.userId = user.id;
        users.push(user);
        updateClients();
    });

    socket.on('disconnect', function () {
        for(var i=0; i<users.length; i++) {
            if(users[i].id == socket.userId) {
                console.log("disconnecting user :"+socket.userId);
                //delete users[socket.user];
                users.splice(i, 1);
            }
        }
        updateClients(); 
    });

    function updateClients() {
        //console.log("server.js updateClients() : users="+users);
        io.sockets.emit('update', users);
    }

});
```

Client Side

```
var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:3000', {'sync disconnect on unload' : true});

    var chatUser = {
        id : user.id,
        fullName : user.firstName + " " + user.lastName,
        imgUrl : user.imgUrl,
        role : user.role
    };

    socket.on('connect', function (){
        console.log("user " + chatUser.id + " connected");
        socket.emit('adduser', chatUser);
    });

    var chatUserList = [];

    socket.on('update', function (chatUsers){
        chatUserList = chatUsers;
        renderChatList(chatUserList);
    });
```

But not getting the proper way to go around.